# how can I use asynctask in fragment?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment, lifecycle

My fragment is doing more stuff , that's why when I open app comes black screen about 3-5 second and show fragment . How can I do when I click app comes progress dialog download stuff and open fragment? In normal activity I do it with  asynctask, But it can't help me in fragment

my code is

in on onActivityCreated GetCategories1.execute();
class GetCategories1 extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(add.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Names...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    pDialog.show();


}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    do my work
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
    populatelistview();

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you say that `AsyncTask` "can't help me in fragment"? What problem are you having using it?

Comment: AsyncTask in a Fragment works just as it does in an Activity.

Comment: when i using asynctask in fragment doesnt load my listview, I have to open another activity then load my listview to fragment. But I want when I open app  immediatly open fragment and show progressbar while download my stuff

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you posted the code in question.

Comment: Maybe you're using the above code as an example, but you aren't returning any results that you can use to populate your ListView.  Can you show your Fragment code as well?  What callback are you using to create and execute this AsyncTask from your Fragment?

Comment: when i use this code in activity it works fine but in fragment stucks

Comment: I solve my problem , thanks for everything , solution is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841618/fragment-implementing-asynctask-and-listview-in-android